# External JavaScript file for all or specific components in angular

Tags: angular

I am new in angular. What I should to do that my external js file to be accessible for all or specific components. For example:

external file: script.js

```
function f(){
  console.log('works :)');
}
```

and TypeScript:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
      f(); // should pring "works :)"
    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot because angular has it's own environment and compilation process, it's based in Typescript, not javascript compiled with webpack, not like javascript interpreted by the browser, so if you have some  business logic you can implement it in a TS file service and call it into your components

Comment: If your JS function is exported, you can directly import that in your TS file. See [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nut8ex) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution can help you:

Your file should be in your src folder or downloaded with npm into node_modules folder.
Then you have to specify the relative path to this file in angular config *(example for angular 8)*.

Part of **angular.json**

```js
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "myProjectName": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
            "scripts": [
              "src/js/my-external-lib.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ...
}
```